# Is Dredd 3D an adaptation of a specific comic storyline?

Tags: comic-adaptation, dredd

Is the new Judge Dredd movie [Dredd 3D](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1343727/) an adaptation or inspired by a specific storyline in the comics or graphic novels?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Dredd 3D is not an adaptation or inspired by a specific storyline.

Alex Garland did consider adapting one of the more well known Judge Dredd storylines such as [Origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origins_%28Judge_Dredd_story%29), but decided that that he would not adapt such a big epic and instead went for an approach of writing an original story - a kind of 'day in the life of Judge Dredd'.

You can read more about this in this [Empire](http://www.empireonline.com/interviews/interview.asp?IID=1530) interview.